# How to compare two sentences by considering the space only in dynamic portion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to compare two sentences. First one is defined in a database like below.

```
var text1 = "Dear {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} Welcome to MAX private ltd"
```

Then the text which comes from customer is given below.

```
"var text2 = "Dear joe harry Welcome to MAX private ltd"
```

Here in place of dynamic there could be any value that customer can substitute and send as an input ( 0- 10) is the character limit for dynamic content.

I need to compare both the sentences and return the response. Problem here is, we should not consider spaces in the other portion of the sentence except for dynamic part. For example,

```
   "var text3 = "Dear joe harry Welcome to MA Xprivatel td"
```

While comparing text1 with text3 , it should be valid even though we have spaces near the MA Xprivatel td". But for dynamic portion , if `{#dynamic#}{#dynamic#}` comes continuously, it can be 20 characters max including spaces. If two
`{#dynamic#} {#dynamic#}` with spaces, max character limit can be 21 including spaces.

My current code is below,

```
   text1 = text1.replace(/(^|.)\s($|.)/g, (x, g1, g2) => (x == "} {" ? "}\\s+{" : g1 + "\\s\*" + g2));
   var separators_regex = /{#dynamic#}|((\s\*))/gi;
   text1= text1.replace(separators_regex, (x, y) => y ? y : ".{0,10}"); 
   let regex1 = RegExp("^" + text1+ "$", "i");
   if (!regex1.test(text2)) {  // or regex1.test(text3)
        Status = "Fail"  
    }
```

Whatever I try, at some scenario it is failing. The above code is failing for text3.
Im stuck with these for too long. Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Try `var rx = new RegExp(text1.replace(/\{#dynamic#}(?:\s*\{#dynamic#})*/g, (x) => '.{0' + ((x.match(/\{#dynamic#}/g) || ['']).length * 10 + (x.match(/\s/g) || '').length) + '}'))`, check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/mswp458a/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for you reply. But it gives failure for me..

Comment: @I forgot the comma after `{0`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/mswp458a/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "Dear {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} Welcome to MAX private ltd {#dynamic#}", => text2= "Dear 123456789012345678900 Welcome to MAX private ltd"  ---- This scenario fails for me. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Does it mean the space(s) before `{#dynamic#}` should become optional?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it should be optional, unless if two {#dynamic#} comes with space in between => Only on this case spaces should be considered...

Comment: Ok, try `var rx = new RegExp(text1.replace(/\s*\{#dynamic#}(?:\s*\{#dynamic#})*/g, (x) =>  '\\s*.{0,' + ((x.match(/\{#dynamic#}/g) || ['']).length * 10 + (x.match(/\s/g) || '').length) + '}'))`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/mswp458a/2/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  For most scenarios it is working perfectly, but var text2 = "Dear 1234567890 12345678901 Welcome to MAX private ltd" => In this case, it should be failed knw, since in the dynamic portion it contains more than 21 digits including space..

Comment: Are you sure? I see exactly 21 chars with 1 space in `1234567890 12345678901`, the pattern thus contains `.{0,22}` part.

Comment: Well, the technique you need is still there. I am posting it so that you could adjust the numbers in the limiting quantifier as you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It should be 0 to 21 digits including spaces, if two {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} comes with space, and it should be 0 to 20 digits if it comes without space {#dymanic#}{#dynamic#} .. whatever regular expression I form, for some scenarios it is getting failed.. I will try altering this. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
var text2 = "Dear 1234567890 12345678901 Welcome to MAX private ltd"
var text1s = ["Dear {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} Welcome to MAX private ltd {#dynamic#}"];
var text2 = "Dear joe harry Welcome to MAX private ltd";
for (var text1 of text1s) {
  var rx = new RegExp(text1.replace(/\s*(\{#dynamic#}(?:\s*\{#dynamic#})*)/g, (x, y) =>
    '\\s*.{0,' + ((y.match(/\{#dynamic#}/g) || ['']).length * 10 + (y.match(/\s/g) || '').length) + '}'))
  console.log(rx)
  console.log(rx.test(text2))  
}
```

This means:

- Sequences of possibly whitespace-separated `{#dynamic#}` chunks are replaced with the necessary `.{0,x}` patterns
- If there are spaces in between, these are added up to `x`
- If there are leading whitesapces, they will be made optional, `\s*` will replace any amount of whitespaces.

Comment: Again  "var text3 = "Dear joe harry Welcome to MA Xprivatel td" for this, it is failing .. Could you please help?

Comment: @sai Ok, I understand the initial whitespace chunk should not be considered. I captured the match after the first `\s*`, and now it must be what you want.

Comment: Dear Sir, it still not working, var text3 = "Dear joe harry Welcome        
          to MAX      privatel td". There may or may not be many spaces in between words, Like i said, spaces should not be considered in the static portion while comparing..

Comment: @sai Do you mean to say there can be any amount of whitespace inside `{#dynamic#}` part? And it is not really `.{0,10}` but more like `(?:\s*\S){0,10}`, only counting non-whitespace chars? Then replace ``'\\s*.{0,'`` with ``'(?:\\s*\\S){0,'``

Comment: No no Sir, like in static portion "Dear  joe harry Welcome (space) (space) (space)  to MAX privatel td".. Here fr example after Welcome or MAX or anywhere except dynamic portion there may or maynot be space or multiple spaces which should match..

Comment: @sai I am afraid it is impossible to help you further. I have no idea of what is "static" here. If there can be no space between `privatel` and `td`, I really do not understand what `{#dynamic#}` has to do with it.

Comment: "Dear {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} Welcome to MAX private ltd {#dynamic#}".. Except whatever has mentioned in dynamic, every other is a static one Sir. Here in the above sentence, Dear , Welcome, to , MAX, private, ltd are the static content. What I need here is, the text2 which i will get from customer, they might include single space or may not include space and can contain multiple spaces between those like "Dear {#dynamic#} {#dynamic#} Welcome<space><space> toMAX private ltd" ..